# How create a brand new Angular project starting from another project?

Tags: angular, angular9

I am pretty new in Angular and I have the following problem.

I have to create a new Angular project starting from an other one (this because I can reuse the entire architecture and a lot of code). What is the best way to do it?

At the moment I copied my old project into another directory and then I changed the reference of the old project with the name of the new one into the following files:

- package.json
- angular.json

But I am not sure that this is the best way to do it. What is the correct procedure to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new project completely clean and use old one as a reference if you need something.

In this case - you will not have unneeded things, will know your code better and will understand your project.

Not everything is brilliant - so copying and pasting is not the best option. Try using good parts and re-thinking what could be better.